# Can I use glUniform4fv to set an individual column of a shader matrix?

Tags: opengl, glsl

Is it possible to obtain the location of a glsl mat4 individual column? I want to update the value of an individual column of a matrix defined in the shader without actually having the set the whole matrix uniform.

I have a game where the camera orientation stays often the same but the translation part changes frequently. My idea was to only update the affected translation part of the VP matrix (projection * view) in order to squeeze some performance.

Comment: Use [Uniform block](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Interface_Block_(GLSL)#Uniform_blocks) or [Shader Storage Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object). Then you can update any subset of the buffer. e.g. by [`glBufferSubData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferSubData.xhtml).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. You can no more set only one column of a matrix uniform than you can set the high two bytes of a `uint` uniform without setting the other two bytes too. When it comes to uniforms, matrices are just as much a basic type as a vector or scalar.

> My idea was to only update the translation part of the view matrix in order to squeeze some performance.

This will not do that. The performance of doing an extremely small CPU-to-GPU memory transfer will be dominated by the overhead of doing *any* CPU-to-GPU transfer. That is, the cost to transfer 16 bytes will be basically identical to the cost of transferring 64 bytes. The amount of data transferred only becomes significant to the cost of the transfer when that amount starts getting large (kilo/mega bytes).

So this is a waste of time. Just transfer the matrix and move on. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to obtain the location of a glsl mat4 individual column?

No.

For a `mat` uniform variable type, you need to use the appropriate `glUnfiformMatrix...()` call, and you cannot update individual parts of it:

Possible alternatives:

- Use an [Uniform Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object) where you can indivudally control every single byte, as already suggested by @Rabbid76's comment.
- Use `uniform vec4 mymat[4]` instead of `mat4` and construct the matrix in the shader (if needed) or directly use the individual column vectors for the calculations.

Comment: Do you think there is much overhead of constructing mat4 inside the shader? My idea was to only update the translation part of a view matrix to boost performance. I´m developing a game where the camera orientation stays the same but it is often translated on the XZ plane.

Comment: @JesúsMartínBerlanga: "*I´m developing a game where the camera orientation stays the same but it is often translated on the XZ plane.*" The performance difference in uploading 16 bytes vs. 64 bytes is non-existent (or *at best*, it will be exceedingly trivial).

Comment: While I agree with @NicolBolas here that is will not make a difference, " I´m developing a game where the camera orientation stays the same but it is often translated on the XZ plane." Why do you even use a `mat4` in the first place? You can encode your complete view transformation in a simple `vec3` (or `vec2` in the 2D case).

Comment: @derhass I use a mat4 VP wich contains proj * view premultiplied on the cpu.

Answer (score 0):

no you can't. generally you don't need to do this because of modern hardware do this kind of cpu to gpu transfer so fast so there is no sensible difference between sending a column or a whole matrix. but in my case (in embedded systems using opengl es) i got a bottleneck in the similar situation. so i change uniforms to attributes. each row of matrix would become a vec4 attribute and we use VBO to send data. frequent data changing would accomplished by [buffer streaming](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming). i don't say this is a good way and will increase performance (hardwares are diffrent) but in my case it works fine.